# Open external URL in simple custom Android browser

Tags: android, url, android-intent, webview, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a simple custom browser to open a single page (for now) by ACTION_VIEW, when I see the log, there are no errors or warnings, but I can't open anyone pages.

This is my class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String url = "";
    if (Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getData()).getHost() != null) {
        url = getIntent().getData().getHost();
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.clearCache(true);
        wv.clearHistory();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        wv.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

}

...I know, at the beginning there is a NullPointerException, but isn't a problem.

Now my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kangel.webviewsample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And this is my simple layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What's wrong? My app show blank page!

Comment: check your layout also... can you show it here ?

Comment: Is it necessary to add cache and history in code?

Comment: could you please Log the `url` parameter after setting `getIntent().getData().getHost()` and post it here? Maybe you should use `getIntent().getData().toString()` instead

Comment: This is the test url: https://picturecode.com/